# create a new map from map<string,Map<String,String>> and map<string,Map<String,Object>> in apex?

Tags: apex, map

I have a `Map<string, Map<String, String>> map1` containing the object as the outer key and the value contains field api name and the label (the label is something which i want to use and not the actual field label)
for example:

```
{
  opportunity={Name=Name information,
   StageName=Stage Name Details,
   Channel__c=channel}
}.
```

I have another `Map<string, Map<String, Object>> map2` containing the object as the outer key and the value contains field api name and its value. for example:

```
{opportunity={Name= new opportunity, stageName= understand customer}.
```

Now i want to merge the two maps so that map2's value contains field label instead of field api name by fetching the field label from map1 and the map should look like the following:

```
Map<string , Map<String, String>> map3--> 
{
  opportunity={
    Name information= new opportunity, 
    stage Name Details= understand customer
}
```

Also, `map1` has the label `Channel__c=channel` but this `channel__c` field is not present in map2. Hence map3 should contain `channel=''`.
i need to display map3 in a table format with the field label as the column name and since `channel__c` is not present in map2, channel column should contain its value as blank in the table.
Is this possible?

Comment: Field labels are not unique. It is unwise to use them as map keys. Stepping back and providing more detail on what end goal you are trying to achieve may reveal a simpler, more reliable solution.

Comment: The labels will be set as unique. So in this case using map1 and map2, can map3 be constructed?